# Passing SharedPreferences to doInBackground()

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to pass the SharedPreferences prefs, as an argument to doInBackground function in AsyncTask. I am already passing a string(url) to it, so I would need to pass the prefs also as a string. Can I simply use, prefs.toString() to convert it into string?

This is where I set the prefs:

```
if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
            prefString = prefs.toString();
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
        }
```

Comment: when you try to use "prefs.toString()" to convert it into string, what happens?

Comment: why not refer to the prefs in the background?

Comment: I didn't know how to do that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't and you shouldn't. You can easily read the preferences just inside `doInBackground()` withou passing anything to the method, simply by using the [`PreferenceManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html):

```
public class DownloadFiles extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {

  Context ctx;

  DownloadFiles(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
  }

  @Override
  public void doInBackground(URL... urls) {
    // ...
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell how to use the PreferenceManager to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: This is good practice? i thought you shouldn't use context in the doInBackground method....

Comment: @Maxrunner can't find a reason why it would not. The Context is only passed to a static method in which its fields are read to resolve names

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
  public class DownloadFiles extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {

      Context ctx;
    boolean firstLaunch;
    SharedPreferences prefs;


      DownloadFiles(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("Prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      }
      @Override
      public void onPreExecute() {
          firstLaunch = prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true);
      }

      @Override
      public void doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        if(firstLaunch)
          // code for the firstLaunch
        else 
          //code if it isn't the firstLaunch 
      }

      @Override
      public void onPostExecute(Void params) {
          // update prefs after the firstLaunch
          if(firstLaunch)
              prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
      }
    }
```

Comment: @LalitPoptani : a Code which is commented very well and explained very well is also a good answer :). and it isn't a wall of code