# How to get context properly to save data into shared preferences from fragment after an asynchronous action?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have such configuration.

1. Activity uses a Fragment showing some cloud application settings.
2. Fragment does a http request to apply changed settings.
3. If the request successes, the application should save the changes into shared preferences and this needs a context object...

The problem is that when the user clicks on the Save button, a http request is executed. If the user decides to leave the Settings screen, then *getActivity()* method of the Fragment returns *null* and I can't save settings into shared preferences. How to resolve that most properly and generally?

Comment: Instead of Activity you can use Application context. But from what i understand if your fragment is closed whole request might not be reachable. The best way should be  making some kind of service (intentService) do the request in background

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are making the service call via an `AsyncTask` (and you should use an `AsyncTask` and not perform the call in UI Thread). In that case, you could save the changes in `SharedPreferences` in the `AsyncTask` itself. For more info refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14053548/4747587

Comment: It isn't a nice solution since it can lead to memory leaks as such an asynctask can keep a reference to the finished activity

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when activity is destroyed - cancel request:

```
@Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        asyncTask.cancel(true);
    }
```

Or if you want save data - block back button, while request is running.